# Chances of publishing paper(s) in last year of PhD

Tags: publications, phd, india

We have a *recent* rule in our institution that **at least two papers need to be published in [SCI journals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Citation_Index)** for being awarded a doctorate degree.

Students were well aware about the rule since the first year of their PhD degree. I called it a recent rule because the university never had this rule prior to this, and this is the first batch of students to whom it applies.

Almost 95% of the students do not have a SCI journal publication in the last year of their PhD. Those who do are from physics or physics. Almost all the rest belongs to computer-science subjects like cryptography, machine learning etc.

We do not have any statistics regarding the possibility of publishing two papers in the last year by PhD students since the rule is relatively new. So, stats of seniors are not much helpful for us.
Most of the seniors published their research papers in the last year of their PhD. But, almost all of these publications are in non-SCI journals. So, their stats are no longer relevant to us.

Many users may answer that it totally depends on the student, supervisor, environment etc.,  But one can observe that only 5% of students get their papers published in their early years and 95% didn't have any progress in publications. So, I am hoping that there would be statistics related to this phenomenon.

Is there any survey or stats regarding this? What percentage of students get their papers published in standard journals in their last year of PhD?

Comment: Likely related to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166991/my-paper-was-rejected-and-some-colleagues-say-this-is-due-to-the-reviewers-mi/167009#167009)

Comment: To make sure I understand your situation: Your university imposed a new rule, and the problem is that this new rule also applies to existing students. If they had known that at the beginning they would (or at least, should) have chosen a different strategy, but that is obviously no longer possible. Is that the main problem you wish to address in this question?

Comment: @MaartenBuis Not exactly, all students know about the rule by the end of their first year of PhD. But, it is the first batch having such rule. Students knows about rule in their earlier stage only.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft 1) Although the name contains the word institute, it started offering a variety of branches in the last ten years including business degrees. 2) The former one. Those without any publication.

Comment: *The former one. Those without any publication.* – That’s weird. Those disciplines always strike me are as having a rather high publication output.

Comment: Also, thinking about it: So 95% of your PhD students are from computer science and similar, 2% from biology, 3% from physics, and (almost) none from business and other fields. Those are weird proportions. Are you sure, this is correct?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yeah.. The Ph.D. degree is not started in the business domain. Currently, the institute is offering a post-graduation on it...

Comment: The "seniors" almost all of whose publications are in non-SCI-indexed journals are the people who've already graduated with Ph.D.s from the institute and now work there (including the supervisors of the current Ph.D. students), right?

Comment: @DanielHatton yeah, some of the people work in the same institute in different domains... Including teaching and non-teaching staff..

Comment: @DanielHatton But not almost. Because many of them work in colleges that have fewer rankings than my institute..

Comment: Maybe it's a compsci thing, but the trouble I'm having is this: if I selected journals to submit to at random from the journals of which I've heard, (much) more than half of those randomly-selected journals would be SCI-indexed.  So I'm finding it hard to understand how a situation arose whereby "almost all" of the seniors' publications are in non-SCI-indexed journals.

Comment: What about the advisors in this? They also know of the requirements and should have been making sure research was done in time to turn into papers and that they were submitted to SCI-indexed journals...